# Huggingface question generation TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am setting up a question generation project on VS Code using Hugging face model valhalla/t5-small-qa-qg-hl

I have trialled this on colab and it works perfectly. The model gets downloaded when the pipeline is created on colab: [image: model download & pipeline setup as visualised on colab]

The same code on VSCode throws error stating the model is not callable. Seems like the download & pipeline setup needs to be done differently if on VScode? Not sure what I might need to do extra here? Any help is appreciated. TIA
[image: The code and error]

The error message reads:
nlp = pipeline("question-generation", model="valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Please edit your post so that it does not contain [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please check your python version of colab and local machine.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?